# AI algorithm model that outputs a list of unknown length

Tags: python, linear-regression, ai, graph-neural-network

I have a dataset with the following x columns:

1. date
2. time
3. is_weekend
4. is_holiday
5. start_intersection
6. end_intersection

The output is a list of intersections, that connect start_intersection with end_intersection. The list is essentially the shortest paths from start to finish

Is there any graph ai models that can generate such shortest path?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. The question is not clear, please explain what is an intersection. At first sight this doesn't look like a ML problem.

Comment: intersection is a road intersection. i am trying to implement something that finds the shortest path from start to finish through a city grid based on traffic densities on the intersections

Comment: Then this is probably a graph problem. You need to design the problem more formally and then probably to convert the data to an appropriate format. Currently it's very unlikely that there is any library specifically for this format and this problem. Btw you didn't mention that this is a shortest path problem in the question.